# Which router is best for angular2 routing

Tags: redux, angular2-routing

Angular2 **realtime** web app routing using

1. redux(ngredux , ngrx)

   ```
        or
   ```
2. angular/router (as they mention in angular2 doc)

   ```
        or
   ```
3. use both

i am very confuse to which routing i have to use in my angular project . please **suggest me best options**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is better to use, Angular2 router.
If you are using one frame work, try to use components provided by the same framework.